# agent-based simulation of software engineering problems?

Tags: agent-based-modeling

Has there been any agent-based simulation models built for investigating software engineering processes or problems? (e.g. collaboration in agile vs. traditional warefall, QA defect trends, open source project growth...etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you didn't find anything, there's some academic work that's related -- for example
[this by Madey, Freeh and Tynan](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.138.1547&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which discusses OSS development as social network, and [this by the same authors](http://www.nd.edu/~oss/Papers/amcis_swarm.pdf) who then go on to model it using [Swarm](http://www.swarm.org)